# Display an error if a latitude or longitude has improper formatting

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application has a dialog where the user can enter a latitude & a longitude.  I have written an `IValueConverter` which can handle values entered as decimal degrees or in degree-minute-second format:

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( double? ), typeof( string ) )]
public class CoordinateConverter : IValueConverter {

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        double angle = 0.0;

        if ( value is string ) {
            if ( !double.TryParse( value as string, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out angle ) ) {
                return value;
            }

        } else if ( value is double || value is double? ) {
            angle = (double) value;

        } else {
            return value.ToString();
        }

        bool isNegative = angle < 0;
        if ( isNegative ) angle = -angle;

        double degrees   = Math.Truncate( angle );
        double remainder = ( angle - degrees ) * 60.0;
        double minutes   = Math.Truncate( remainder );
        double seconds   = ( remainder - minutes ) * 60.0;

        string result = degrees.ToString( "##0", culture.NumberFormat ) + "° " +
                        minutes.ToString( "#0", culture.NumberFormat ) + "' " +
                        seconds.ToString( "#0.00", culture.NumberFormat ) + "\" ";

        // The parameter contains "NS" for Latitudes and "EW" for Longitudes.
        if ( parameter != null ) {
            result += ( (string) parameter ).Substring( ( isNegative ? 1 : 0 ), 1 );
        } else {
            result = ( isNegative ? "-" : string.Empty ) + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        string strValue = value as string;

        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( strValue ) ) {
            return null;
        }

        double adjustForSign = 1.0;
        if ( strValue.IndexOf( "-" ) >= 0 ) {
            adjustForSign = -1.0;
            strValue = strValue.Substring( strValue.IndexOf( "-" ) + 1 );
        }

        // Parse the value in the field.  It's in three parts:  Degrees, minutes & seconds
        int degreeSymbol = strValue.IndexOf( "°" );
        int minuteSymbol = strValue.IndexOf( "'" );
        int secondSymbol = strValue.IndexOf( '"' );

        string degrees = null, minutes = null, seconds = null;
        double angle, d, m, s;

        if ( degreeSymbol < 0 ) {
            if ( double.TryParse( strValue, NumberStyles.Number, culture.NumberFormat, out angle ) ) {
                return angle;
            } else {
                return value;
            }

        } else {
            degrees = strValue.Substring( 0, degreeSymbol );

            if ( minuteSymbol >= 0 ) {
                minutes = strValue.Substring( degreeSymbol + 2, minuteSymbol - degreeSymbol - 2 );
            }
            if ( secondSymbol < 0 ) {
                seconds = "0" + culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "0";
            } else {
                seconds = strValue.Substring( minuteSymbol + 2, secondSymbol - minuteSymbol - 2 );
            }
        }

        if ( !double.TryParse( degrees, NumberStyles.Integer, culture.NumberFormat, out d ) ) return value;
        if ( !double.TryParse( minutes, NumberStyles.Integer, culture.NumberFormat, out m ) ) return value;
        if ( !double.TryParse( seconds, NumberStyles.Float  , culture.NumberFormat, out s ) ) return value;
        angle = d + m / 60.0 + s / 3600.0;

        if ( parameter != null ) {
            if ( strValue.Contains( ( (string) parameter ).Substring( 1, 1 ) ) ) {
                angle = -angle;
            }
        } else {
            angle *= adjustForSign;
        }
        return angle;
    }
```

In the dialog, I'm using this `ControlTemplate` to display errors:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="InputErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right"
               Height="20"
               Margin="-30,0,0,0"
               Source="{StaticResource ErrorImage}"
               ToolTip="{x:Static res:Car.Common_InvalidData}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Width="20" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="5"
                Margin="5,0,30,0">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If one of the `TextBoxes` has a string in it like , it doesn't parse, no exceptions are thrown, and my dialog's error template is displayed.  When I hover the mouse over the `TextBox`, the error message displayed is "Input string is not in a correct format"

I have a couple of questions:

1. Where is that error message coming from?  It's not in my code and if the converter throws an exception, the program dies as it's unhandled.
2. In the end, I want to display an error if the value in the `TextBox` can't be parsed.  The dialog's View Model object does implement `IDataErrorInfo`, but the conversion from string to double isn't being done by that object.  How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the textbox is probably bound to a double property in the code-behind, I think there is some clever pre-conversion validation which gives the validation error you see. 
To control the validation process, I think there are several ways to go about it:

- You can make you own validation rule
- You can return a validationresult from the converter (although IMO
  validation and conversion don't really seem to belong together)
- You
  can make use of the IDataError interface and MVVM

Here are a couple of links which provide some good information:

- [Using a ViewModel to Provide Meaningful Validation Error Messages](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/)
- [Data validation in WPF](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)
- [Using Custom Validation Rules in WPF](http://developingfor.net/2009/10/13/using-custom-validation-rules-in-wpf/)

One more thing, when converting the input to double, is there any particular reason to use Invariant culture instead of the culture passed as parameter? It might fail on a non-english culture (e.g. Danish), where the decimal separator is a comma (which is equivalent to thousand separator in English culture).

Comment: My application has a number of `IValueConverter` classes, some of which are passed data parsed from an XML file, which encodes everything using the Invariant Culture. I recently added the `value is string` case to handle parsing that data to all of the converters.  However, this particular class may not need that logic.  I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Incidentally, this dialog does use MVVM & the view model implements the `IDataError` interface.  I didn't mention it in the question because it seemed irrelevant -- in my mind, the question was about the `IValueConverter` and not the view model.  The display of latitude & longitude as degrees - minutes - seconds has nothing to do with validating if the values entered are acceptable.  And yes, the properties in question are doubles.  To do that validation in the view model, I'd have to bind the text boxes to string properties & do the conversion to double in there.  Not a bad idea, I might add.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for a while, I've found that the binding seems to try to cast whatever value the `Convert` or `ConvertBack` methods return into the correct type based on the direction data is flowing.  If the value cannot be cast into that type, the "Input string is not in a correct format" message is added to the error collection for that control.  So if my code just returns the original value unchanged if there's a problem, I end up getting that message.

That message is good enough, at least for now.  If I want a different message, I'll have to investigate creating a validation rule or some other mechanism.